# AD Reflection - How does it work?

Tags: haskell, reflection, typeclass, instances, automatic-differentiation

I have seen the `ad` package and i understand how it does automatic differentiation by providing a different instance of the `class Floating` and then implementing the rules of derivatives.

But in the example

```
Prelude Debug.SimpleReflect Numeric.AD> diff atanh x
recip (1 - x * x) * 1
```

We see that it can represent **functions** as `AST`s and show them as a string with variable names.

I wonder how they did that, because when i write:

```
f :: Floating a => a -> a
f x = x^2
```

No matter what instance I provide, i will get a **function** `f :: Something -> Something`
and not a representation like `f :: AST`, or `f :: String`

The instance cannot "know" what the parameters are.

How they are able to do it ?

Comment: `ad` package uses a lot of magic underhood and a lot of custom type classes. Not actually about `ad` but you can watch this video about designing `AutomaticDifferentiation` library: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1DUKEOUoxA&t=4322s

Comment: Note that to get `recip (1 - x * x) * 1`, you had to apply `diff atanh` to `x`. The simple `x` is unassuming, but it's the core of the magic you see here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the AD package, actually, and everything to do with the `x` in `diff atanh x`.

To see this, let's define our own AST type

```
data AST = AST :+ AST
         | AST :* AST
         | AST :- AST
         | Negate AST
         | Abs AST
         | Signum AST
         | FromInteger Integer
         | Variable String
```

We can define a `Num` instance for this type

```
instance Num (AST) where
  (+) = (:+)
  (*) = (:*)
  (-) = (:-)
  negate = Negate
  abs = Abs
  signum = Signum
  fromInteger = FromInteger
```

And a `Show` instance

```
instance Show (AST) where
  showsPrec p (a :+ b) = showParen (p > 6) (showsPrec 6 a . showString " + " . showsPrec 6 b)
  showsPrec p (a :* b) = showParen (p > 7) (showsPrec 7 a . showString " * " . showsPrec 7 b)
  showsPrec p (a :- b) = showParen (p > 6) (showsPrec 6 a . showString " - " . showsPrec 7 b)
  showsPrec p (Negate a) = showParen (p >= 10) (showString "negate " . showsPrec 10 a)
  showsPrec p (Abs a) = showParen (p >= 10) (showString "abs " . showsPrec 10 a)
  showsPrec p (Signum a) = showParen (p >= 10) (showString "signum " . showsPrec 10 a)
  showsPrec p (FromInteger n) = showsPrec p n
  showsPrec _ (Variable v) = showString v
```

So now if we define a function:

```
f :: Num a => a -> a
f a = a ^ 2
```

and an AST variable:

```
x :: AST
x = Variable "x"
```

We can run the function to produce either integer values or AST values:

```
λ f 5
25
λ f x
x * x
```

If we wanted to be able to use our AST type with your function `f :: Floating a => a -> a; f x = x^2`, we'd need to extend its definition to allow us to implement `Floating (AST)`.

Comment: It's worth noting explicitly that the Debug.SimpleReflect module is where the `x` comes from in the example.